# read and extract entries in python

Tags: python

Following is my code to read and extract certain patterns.

```
fo = open("result.txt")
line = fo.readline()
while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
    if "start_indi" in line:
        line = fo.readline()
        offset = line.split(':')[0] 
        length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
        print("["+ offset + ":" + length + "]")
        line = fo.readline()
        while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
            if line.contains(int(offset_value)+ int(length_value)+":"):
                print(line)
```

I start reading my entries when i get my predefined indicator **start_indi** and would like to get the output as **[2286:5321]**, but i am getting it as **[2286:5321 cons: next]**
also i want to continue extracting the `offsets` and `lengths` as long as they satisfy the condition

next_offset = prev_offset + prev_length
so in my file the next_offset will be at some random point i will read based on that condition.
please help

sample data in my file:

```
2282:depth=3  hl=4 l=12096 cons: start_indi        
2286:depth=4  hl=4 l=5321 cons: next          
2290:depth=5  hl=4 l=4785 cons: next          
2294:depth=6  hl=2 l=   1 base: type           :01
```

Updated my code to calculate next offset, but it does not seem to be correct

Comment: fix the indenation of your code and also post sample data from your text file

Comment: Done, tried multiple time for indentation, there seems some problem , could not post here.

Comment: as per you data the output will contain one line only because only line 1 contains the "start_indi"

Comment: (1) You can split "length" at space character to remove the unwanted part. (2) You can use a flag variable which is set to "True" when indicator is encountered and check for state of this flag.

Comment: Try adding length = length.split(" ")[0] before your print

Comment: if i use like this > length = line.split(' ')[4] , the i will get l=5321,  just want only number

Comment: It seems that your offset is the previous offset + previous hl.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\d+):.* l=(\d+) .*')
with open('result.txt') as f:
    result = [re.findall(p, line)[0]
     for line in f if "start_indi" in line and len(line.strip()) != 0]
```

You can correct your code as follows:

```
fo = open("result.txt")
next_offset = 0

for line in fo:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0 or "start_indi" in line:
        continue

    if next_offset == 0 or str(next_offset) + ':' in line:
        offset = line.split(':')[0]
        length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
        print(line)
        print("[" + offset + ":" + length + "]")
        next_offset = int(offset) + int(length)

fo.close()
```

Comment: @promote, yes this works fine for extracting [offset:length], now i need to try for next offset , which is a sum of prev offset and prev length

Comment: Any clue on how to do that, because here i need to find an integer value in the line then parse it.

Comment: Convert it to an integer: int(length)

Comment: @promote , updated the code , can you please correct me

Comment: this line generating syntax error at last single quote if f'{int(offset)+ int(length)}:' in line:

Comment: still i get the error at this line if next_offset == 0 or f'{next_offset}:' in line: at the last singe quote,i am not much familiar with python syntax, also we need not to check for start_indi second time, only one time is enough

Comment: It should work with your Python version. Otherwise, update it.

Comment: I have 2.7.15 version,cannot upgrade there is a limitation

Answer (score 0):

```
fo = open("result.txt");
line = fo.readline()
while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
    if "start_indi" in line:
        line = fo.readline()
        offset = line.split(':')[0]
        length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
        length_i = int (length) + 4
        offset_i = int (offset)
        print("["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]")
        line = fo.readline()
        while len(line.strip()) != 0 :
            if str(offset_i + length_i) + ':' in line:
                offset = line.split(':')[0]
                length = line.split('=')[3].split()[0]
                length_i = int (length) + 4
                offset_i = int (offset)
                print("["+ offset + ":" + str (length_i) + "]")
            line = fo.readline()
    line = fo.readline()
```

The above program works well for my requirement, but looking for some what robust check & concise way of doing it, any help will be much appreciated.